# How to deselect all choices of the django-autocomplete-light widget via javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, django-autocomplete-light

I need to clear an already selected value of the `django-autocomplete-light` widget via javascript (or may be reload the widget, if it is more simple).
How can it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I have only one auto-complete widget on a page and only one item is selected.

This code deselects the item:

```
var widget = $('.autocomplete-light-widget').yourlabsWidget();
var choice = $('span.div.hilight');
widget.deselectChoice(choice);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a widget that only allows 1 item to be selected so I used this code to reset the field and run the `deselectChoice` event.

```
var widget = $('.autocomplete-light-widget').yourlabsWidget();
widget.freeDeck()
```